# deploying React.js and Node.js application with Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have deployed my first application to Heroku and the website domain can be reached but when I try to loving I get the following set of error messages.

> login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://unit-backend.herokuapp.com/property/login' from origin 'http://unit-website.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**NODE**

I have already added the CORS library and tried giving permission these ways: 
`app.use(cors({ origin: "https://unit-website.herokuapp.com" }));`

```
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://unit-website.herokuapp.com"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

I am not sure if this error is CORS related or there is a bug in my code. when I run Heroku open on the backend side I get the following error:

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/property/login" host=unit-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=8bd46aae-91cb-4d25-ba61-5f454fac68d2 fwd="73.83.19.43" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

**REACT**

I have my environment variables set in two files one is the production which has

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://unit-backend.herokuapp.com
```

and the other one is the development which has

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:6969
```

If you need more information let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Random suggestion but... Do you have any res.sendStatus in ur backend? I was receiving cors error because of it  and had to change it to res.send(string). Not sure what are u using for the back, but its a wild guess

Comment: No, I am using res.send and res.status. It is a weird error because I don't think the error is CORS related at all.

Comment: I had cors errors because i was using res.status and res. Sendstatus. It was weird and random and i havent found a solution yet. Maybe try changing the call to res.send(string). (I think its /login in that api)

Comment: I tried that but still got the same error messages. But good idea.